# Bash - Assigning existing Variable values to a New Variable. New Variable values does not return the assigned value

Tags: bash, shell, variables, sh

I want to assign a value of the existing Variable to a new Variable in my Bash script.
The issues is that once the New variable gets assigned to a value of the existing Variable it returns none instead of returning the existing variable value. (see code below):

```
VAR1="Hello World"
VAR2="Let's concatenate"

VAR1+="$MyVar" # assigning to a new variable
echo "$VAR1"
echo "$MyVar" # This is the issue --> no value returned (intention is to return "Hello World")
```

The output is for this command (echo "$MyVar") is:

- VAR1=
- echo ''

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot suggests you are executing `VAR1="$MyVar"`, not `VAR1+="$MyVar'`. (Both are wrong, but there's an inconsistency here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't defining a new variable named `MyVar`. You are appending the empty string resulting from the expansion of the non-existent variable to the value of `VAR1`.

You want

```
MyVar=$VAR1
```

to get the desired result.

---

An example of what `+=` *does* do:

```
$ x=foo
$ echo "$x"
foo
$ x+=bar
$ echo "$x"
foobar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification @chepner

Comment: Does it meant that if I concatenate and empty string (eg: MyVar) to an existing string that has some value it will return None? Like in SQL when Appending NULL to a value it returns NULL?

Comment: @enigma6205 No that’s not the case. Appending an empty string to a variable will leave the variable unchanged. In your original post, `$MyVar` is never set, anywhere, hence it is empty.

Comment: `x=foo; x+=""; echo "$x"` will output `foo`. This is easily checked.